# Does a large amount of helper functions increase the bundle size sent to the client?

Tags: reactjs

I am currently working on a project where we do a lot of parsing of data on the frontend side. The project has a lot of helper functions used to change data structures etc. It is written with React (create-react-app) on the frontend and .Net on the backend. My question is: Does this increase the bundle size of the application sent to the client in a way the user will notice?

Answer (score 1):

If you are defining the function every time & not importing a more generic function from your utilities, there would be more code shipped to the client which would increase the bundle size. But I would suggest that your biggest issue would not be with bundle size, but more with speed. because the calculations (if not optimized, or too complex) would possibly block the UI. you can test that by going to your performance tab in chrome dev-tools & change the CPU performance to 4x-slowdown and then do some interaction where you are doing your data manipulation. if you see lagging UI, you can start by memoizing the values that come out of the operations, so it wouldn't be calculated on each render.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. We are using generic utils, and I could not see any UI lags. Thats a nice dev tool trick tho!